# Is it possible to avoid from an activity that the application is closed?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigationbar

I am trying to prevent my application from being closed once in a specific `activity`, and that the only way that allows the user to leave this application is to `logout` from the aforementioned `activity`, so that from the login screen he can exit the same without problem, it is possible to achieve that somehow the application can not be closed or sent to the background from the moment you enter an `activity`?

I'm trying to make a `fullscreen` to hide the `navigationBar` and thus prevent the user from leaving the app, the problem is that when you press volume buttons or make gestures at the edges the `navigationBar` is shown again.

```
private void FullScreenMethod() {
        final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
```

I want to prevent the `navigationBar` from showing again unless the user logs in, what I have achieved is to hide it, and when a gesture is made the `navigationBar` shows up for a few seconds and goes back into hiding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, you can not prevent users from leaving your app like that. You will only frustrate users if you attempt to lock them in.

Comment: I understand and in fact I had doubts that it was possible, that is why I had thought about this way of doing it, I also understand the bad experience for the user but it must be this way because of the data that the application will handle.